# How to correctly save a CatBoost to Google Cloud Storage in Python

Tags: google-cloud-storage, catboost

How do I save a trained CatBoost model to Google Cloud Storage?

I have the following CatBoost model training code:

```
    bst_model = _get_catboost_classifier(setting)

    bst_model.fit(train_x, train_y, cat_features=categorical_indicies, verbose = 3)

    bst_model.save_model(f"gs://gchidam-tnt-input-data/bst_model",
           format="cbm",
           export_parameters=None,
           pool=None)
```

it is throwing the following error

```
  File "_catboost.pyx", line 4998, in _catboost._CatBoost._save_model
  File "_catboost.pyx", line 5010, in _catboost._CatBoost._save_model
_catboost.CatBoostError: (No such file or directory) util/system/file.cpp:857: can't open "gs://gchidam-tnt-input-data/bst_model_7490" with mode WrOnly|CreateAlways|Seq (0x00000034)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this github [thread](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/2197#issuecomment-1284568301) by andrey-khropov.

> This error most likely means that the CatBoost training process does
> not have the permissions to write to the current directory.
>
> The default training directory path can be changed by specifying
> `train_dir` parameter or writing any files can be disabled during
> training by specifying `allow_writing_files=False`.